# How to get the name of the directory for each file with a specific file extension in a directory tree?

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, directory

I need to get the name of the directory for each file with extension *.txt within specified folder/directory *(including its subfolders/subdirectories)*.

I've tried the solution from here: [Parent folder from full path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29972788)

But it looks like that `set "myPath=%%~Pa"` doesn't do anything in the code below:

```
@echo off

cd /d "F:\Game\"
for /r %%f in (*.txt) do (
    echo file: %%f
    set "myPath=%%~Pa"
    echo myPath: %myPath%
    for %%a in ("%myPath:~0,-1%") do (
        set "myParent=%%~Na"
        echo %myParent%
    )
)
pause.
```

For these files:

```
F:\Game\file1.txt
F:\Game\first_subfolder\file2.txt
F:\Game\first_subfolder\hellothere\file3.txt
F:\Game\first_subfolder\hellothere\lala\file4.txt
```

I expect to get the name of the directory for each of them:

```
Game
first_subfolder
hellothere
lala
```

How to get the name of the directory for each text file in directory tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest first opening a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, running `set /?` and reading the output help from top of first page to bottom of last page, especially the section about delayed environment variable expansion. See also: [Variables are not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/).

But it is possible to get the directory name for each *.txt file in directory tree without using [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

```
@echo off
for /R %%I in (*.txt) do for %%J in ("%%~dpI.") do (
    echo Text file: %%I
    echo Directory: %%~nxJ
)
```

**Note:** `%%~nxJ` is an empty string if this batch file is executed from root of a drive and there is a *.txt file in root of this drive.

The trick here is `%%~dpI` expands to full path of current text file ending with a backslash. `.` is concatenated to this path string to reference the folder. Then `%%~nxJ` expands to name of the folder without path. See also the Microsoft documentation page [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file).